# Yii2 - How do I AutoLoad a custom class?

Tags: php, yii2

I have created the following custom class that I'd like to use in my Yii2 application:

*@common/components/helper/CustomDateTime.php*

```
namespace common\components\helper;
class CustomDateTime{function Now() {...}}
```

I want to use this class like this:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $account = $this->findModel($id);
    $account->archived = 1;
    $account->archived_date = CustomDateTime::Now();
    $account->save();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

In my @common/config/bootstrap.php file I've created a classMap according to this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html.

```
Yii::$classMap['CustomDateTime'] = '@common/components/helper/CustomDateTime.php';
```

But I am getting the error: *Class 'app\controllers\myapp\CustomDateTime' not found*

**QUESTION:** How do I create a classMap so that I don't have to use the **use** statement at the beginning of every controller to access my custom class?

Yii 1.1 used to have an option in the config file to 'import' a set of code so that a class file could be autoloaded when it was called.

**SOLUTION**

Many thanks to @Animir for redirecting me back to the original documentation.  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html.

I found that I can use the following in my *@common/config/bootstrap.php* file

```
Yii::$classMap['CustomDateTime'] = '@common/components/helper/CustomDateTime.php';
```

BUT - it only works when the the CustomDateTime.php file does NOT have a declared namespace.

```
//namespace common\components\helper;
class CustomDateTime{function Now() {...}}
```

Comment: So are you actually using that everywhere or just lazy :)? Also use a better IDE because good IDEs will automatically include the file when you use it.

Comment: I'm still new to php, so I don't fully understand what lazy loading means.  My goal is to not clutter the top of every php file with a long list of use statements.

Comment: I was not talking about lazy loading I was talking about you being lazy. You cannot possibly need that in every class (unless what you want to do is incredibly dumb). Learn how namespaces work or go to procedural programming.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `use` statement in file, where you use a class.

```
use common\components\helper\CustomDateTime;
/* some code */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $dateNow = CustomDateTime::Now();
    /* some code */
}
/* some code */
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.  I don't want to use the **use** statement for every class I want to reference.

Comment: He wants bootstrap autoloader.

Comment: Yii2 autoload founded on namespaces autoload. Look PSR standarts if you don't know how it works.

But if you do not want to use Yii2 way, you can just to use `require_once` function in `bootstrap.php` to include file with class.

Comment: As you can see class map example from link you provided use namespace to assign class name and path

`Yii::$classMap['foo\bar\MyClass'] = 'path/to/MyClass.php';`
Try this way.

Comment: But PHP try to looking for `CustomDateTime` in current namespace and in root namespace after this. So file, where you want to use `CustomDateTime` class, must be the same as class namespace.

Another way is adding class name with NS to `Yii::$classMap` and using full namespace when calling func like this `$dateNow = foo\bar\CustomDateTime::Now();`

Answer (score 4):

You can do [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0/) way too without the use of `use`

`Yii::$app->cdt->Now(); // cdt - CustomDateTime`

but for this thing to get accomplished successfully you add below to `app/config/web.php` (the config file)

```
...
'components' => [ 
    'cdt' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\helper\CustomDateTime',
    ],
    ...
]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto load in Yii 2 is pretty easy. You can use it by loading the class with config main file. like

You have created your class in components/helper/CustomDateTime.php . and now in your config/main.php in the top of the file add below code

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../components/helper/CustomDateTime.php');
```

Now your class is autoloaded in your project where ever you want to use it you can use like in your controller,model or view

Simply use like this

```
CustomDateTime-><methodName>();
```

Try this i have used this in my project.

For refrence you can use this link. click [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been long since this question was asked. I came across this and to share what I do.

I usually use an alias after `use` statement instead of adding 100 of lines of use statements for each model or class objects. Adding classMap for many of the classes that you use is not a good idea in my view. If you do that you'll be just adding unnecessary mapping even when you are not using those objects.

Here's what I do

```
use Yii;
use common\helpers as Helper;
use yii\helpers as YiiHelper;
use common\models as Model;
use common\components as Component;
```

And in the controller

```
public function actionIndex(){
   $model = Model\SomeModel();

   if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
       $post = Yii::$app->request->post('SomeModel');
       $model->text = Helper\Text::clean($post['text']);
       $model->text = YiiHelper\Html::encode($model->text);

       if($model->save()){
           return $this->render('thank_you');
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps :)