# How to have class loaded without using "use" but call it as if I used it

Tags: yii2

I have studied these 2 sources, but none of those works for me.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html

[Yii2 - How do I AutoLoad a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228407/yii2-how-do-i-autoload-a-custom-class)

I have created custom helper class which I want to include in every model, controller and view in my application. I am using Yii2 advanced app version 2.0.11, IDE I am using is PHPStorm

QUESTION:

**What I want to achieve is to not use `use` keyword at the beggining of every class but still be able to simply call `AppHelper::myMethod()` in models, controllers and views.**
**How is that possible?**

Closest I got it working was using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35160997/5395463

All other solutions did not work for me. I am getting errors like:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException 
Class 'frontend\controllers\AppHelper' not found
```

when I simply dont include  `use commons\commands\AppHelper;` 
or when not using namespace as they suggest there with other settings:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'yii\base\UnknownClassException' 
with message 'Unable to find 'common\commands\AppHelper' 
in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\domain.com\web\common/commands/AppHelper.php.
 Namespace missing?' in ...
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks for your responses, I got it working finaly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330631/5395463 solution works best for me.
So I removed `namespace` from that class, but left it in common\commands folder, added `require` to `frontend/web/index.php` and `backend/web/index.php` files (not sure if I should add it to `yii` file in root too, I didnt, so far it is working good anyways), and changed calls of class from `AppHelper::myMethod()` to `\AppHelper::myMethod()` looks like eveything is working now.

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: I mean why not create custom component that will be available everywhere by calling `\Yii::$app->component_name`? Oh, I see this is mentioned in the solution you marked as closest.

Comment: reason is I am very lazy person, and I dont want to type everytime entire `\commons\commands\AppHelper::myMethod()` nor `use \commons\commands\AppHelper;` at begining of every file

Comment: So component solution is good for you. Why do you need to type it everytime? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Because I am using methods from that class in 90% of files in my app, but I dont want to type entire `Yii::$app...` code. IDE I am using is PHPStorm

Comment: PHPStorm gives you hints about class name while you type and automatically adds `use` statement when you select proper class and there is no `use` of it already added. Additionally you can make yourself some macro that will print `Yii::$app->xxx` when you use your key combination.

Comment: I use mass replace here and there, and in that case it wont add it automaticaly, so that is another reason why I would like to avoid `use`. That macro shortcut seems like good idea, idk why I forgot phpstorm has that, thanks. You might want to add is as answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for not lazy coders:

- create component with your class so you can use it like `\Yii::$app->my_component`
- if even this is too much and your IDE is better than Windows Notepad prepare macro that will print this for you

Solution for lazy coders:

- Save your class in single PHP file without namespace.
- Modify you entry script to include this class - i.e. for Basic Project Template it's `/web/index.php`; add there

  ```
  require(__DIR__ . '/path/to/MyClass.php');
  ```

  For Advanced Project Template modify it properly.
- Now you can use your class by calling it like `\MyClass` (yes, `\` is required and yes, your IDE probably will modify it anyway to `MyClass` with `use MyClass;` added at the beginning.

Comment: using 2nd solution I get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AppHelper in ...` also, how would I use constants and statics methods with `\Yii::$app->my_component` ?

Comment: You removed namespace from that file? Try to place in in root folder and modify path to it in entry script.

Comment: so I removed namespace, left it in common\commands, added require to index files, and changed calls of class. I had other files in common\commands using AppHelper class, when I added \ so it was calling `\AppHelper::myMethod()` looks like eveything is working now

Answer (score 3):

In Yii2  You can  use an explicit way    adding \  to full namespaced  name

```
 \frontend\controllers\AppHelper
```

so you can sue your method

```
 \frontend\controllers\AppHelper::yourMethod();
```

Comment: this is solution for not lazy coders, so not what I am looking for :)

Comment: @Ripper    when i want use eg: a static function (tipically  an helpers function in a common class ) i  use this way .. .. (and normally i place the class in common area .. but you can use a  module  too ..... anyway thanks