# Yii2 - extension structures

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, yii2-extension

Recently I added a telegram bot extension in my Yii2 application to use it. but actually it is not a Yii2 extension but its a normal php namespace structured files and classes.

the name of this telegram extension is `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk` actualy its the name that added to my `composer.json`. I want to know how can I make some classess like this extension?

the `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk` structure is like this:

```
vandor >>
    irazasyed
        telegram-bot-sdk
            composer.json
            license
            src
                class1.php
                class2.php
```

and the class files can be accessed from the namespace like `\Telegram\Bot\Api` from any controller in my application.

i want to know how can I make something like this myself.
I want this structure:

```
vendor >>
    myCustomName
        myCustomPakageName
            composer.json
            license
            src
                Class1.php
                Class2.php
```

and access the class files from this namespace `\something\somethingElse\Class1;`

how can I do this?

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html

Comment: of course i did. My question is how to make it not how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your files in a folder (or folders) in the project folder and use suggested root namespace. You don't need composer.json since you don't need to install it using composer. And you should not put it in `vendor` folder.

Example for basic project template:
- put everything in `myCustomName` folder in application root folder,
- set namespaces for each class like `app\myCustomName` (+ whatever subfolder you are using)

Example for advanced project template:
- put everything in `myCustomName` folder in selected application root folder (like `frontend` or `common`),
- set namespaces for each class like `frontend\myCustomName` (or `common` instead of `frontend` or whatever + whatever subfolder you are using)

Comment: actually currently I using this approach myself. I want to do it without the `\frontend\ ` part in the name. is it possible? lets say I am in backend controller and myCustom folder is in frontend so I should use `\frontend\myCustom+...` but I want to use something like the namespace I said in my question.

Comment: In this case you need to register your root namespace for autoloaders. One of the solutions can be [found in my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42330631/3364821)